# Can't connect to JMS Server configured with LDAP - status = 35

Tags: authentication, ldap, jms

for some reason we cannot connect to a JMS server that is using LDAP for user authentication.

We get back **status = 35**, but reading the doc doesn't really make me any wiser.

```
35  Is a leaf.  Used by the LDAP provider; usually doesn't generate an exception.
```

[LDAP Status Codes and JNDI Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/models/exceptions.html)

Any clues what this means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested,

This is what was written to the log file

```
2013-12-17 16:55:09.271 ERROR: unable to bind to LDAP server as: 'CN=svcLDAPbind,OU=nonpersonal,OU=users,OU=app,dc=dev,dc=agf,dc=america,dc=mgmnt', Can't contact LDAP server
2013-12-17 16:55:09.271 ERROR: LDAP authentication failed for user 'tsv44709', status = 35
```

We rebooted the machine where the JMS(TIBCO EMS) server is running and somehow it also solved our problem, we can now connect to the JMS server again.